# Azure Data Factory copy data from json string nested in a json

Tags: json, etl, azure-data-factory, orchestration

I am fetching data from a third party API, which responds with a JSON payload. However, this JSON contains another JSON object, stored as a string including escape characters. Example:

```
{
    "aggregationType": "IDENTITY",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "Sinusoid|Sinusoid"
        }
    ],
    "value": "{\"dataX\":[1,2,3,4],\"dataY\":[1,4,9,16]}"
}
```

In the first part of the file, we have some regular parameters like 'aggregationType' and 'outputs', but the last parameter 'value' is the JSON object I am talking about.

What I would like to do is to enter the 'dataX' and 'dataY' arrays together into a table on a SQL DB. I haven't found a straightforward way of doing it so far.

What I've tried:

- Using a simple copy activity, but I can only access the whole 'value' field, not separate out 'dataX' from 'dataY', let alone the array's individual values.
- Using the lookup activity to then store 'value' in a variable. From here I can get to a usable JSON object in ADF, but the only way I've found of then sending the data to the DB is to use a ForEach activity containing a copy activity. Since dataX and dataY are in reality much larger, this seems to take forever when I debug.
- Copying only the 'value' object to a blob and trying to retrieve the data from there. This hasn't worked because the object always ends up getting stored with the initial " marks and the \ escape characters.

Is there any way of getting around this issue?

Comment: How exactly do you want the target table to look?  Will it be 8 columns, integer data type for example?  Or two columns (x ,y) of json type?

Comment: I would like to enter the data in two columns (x, y), both integer types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value in a staging kind of table in SQL and then create a stored procedure to separate out the objects as arrays

JSON_Value can help you extract values:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"dataX": [1,2,3,4]}', '$.dataX') AS 'Output';
```

In your stored procedure you can try using above query and insert values in SQL table

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hadn't tried this yet because I was worried about keeping this process as repeatable as possible without requiring more SQL code each time. But at this point, I think I need to give it a go. I will comment again once I'm done.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same code, you can make the field names dynamic or parameterized :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand, on the tip from @Pratik Somaiya, I've written up a stored procedure that does the work of inserting the data to a persistent table.

I've had to use a WHILE loop, which doesn't really feel right, so I'm still on the lookout for a better solution on that.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dataset_outputs_from_adf
    @json_output_value NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @output_name NVARCHAR(100)
AS
    DECLARE @i INT = 0
    WHILE JSON_VALUE(@json_output_value,CONCAT('$.dataX[',@i,']')) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO my_table
        VALUES (
            @output_name,
            JSON_VALUE(
                @json_output_value,
                CONCAT('$.dataX[',@i,']')
            ),
            JSON_VALUE(
                @json_output_value,
                CONCAT('$.dataY[',@i,']')
            )
        )
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
GO
```

I should be able to make the whole thing repeatable without repetitive code by parameterizing Data Factory with the output name.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you can retrieve the embedded "value" JSON but it retains its escape characters. You would like to pass the arrays `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,4,9,16]` to a relational database (Microsoft SQL Server?) to store them.

The embedded "value" can be converted to referencable JSON using the expression [json()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json). This handles the escaped characters.

```
@json(variables('payload')).dataX
```

Will return the array `[1,2,3,4]` as expected.

How best to get this into SQL Server? We are limited to the activities ADF supports, which really comes down to a stored procedure (SP). Using a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) would be ideal, but not possible in current ADF. So I would suggest passing it to the SP as a string.

```
@string(json(variables('payload')).dataX)
```

This will look much the same as above but will be a *string* not an *array*.

In the SP there are a couple of ways to parse this string. If your version supports it [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) is convenient. Note the passed string will retain its leading and trailing square bracket. These can be removed in ADF or in SQL, it doesn't much matter where.

Since the data is JSON it may make more sense to use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-the-default-schema-sql-server) instead. Let's say we pass the contents of dataX to a SP parameter `@dataX varchar(4000)`. Inside the SP we write

```sql
create procedure dbo.HandleData
  @dataX varchar(4000),
  @dataY varchar(4000)
as

insert dbo.SomeTable(ColumnX, ColumnY)
select x.value, y.value
from OPENJSON(@dataX) x
inner join OPENJSON(@dataY) y
    on y.[key] = x.[key];
```

Further code may be needed if the arrays could be of different lengths, or there are NULLs, or non-integer values etc. Of course the resultset from OPENJSON can be used for joining or any other purpose within the SP.

If both dataX and dataY from the original payload end up in the same DB table the SP can be called twice, once for each. Alternatively you can [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#union) their arrays in ADF and call the SP once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael! I'll try and upgrade my stored procedure to no longer use that WHILE loop now, using your suggestions.